# Static margin-left and margin-right for footer in Wordpress' wpocean theme

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

I have trouble finding the proper selector for placing the content of my footer with static `{margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px}` for desktop like[image]. Here's the link to the page I am working http://neu.der-polstergeist.de/.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to add 20px **"Left & Right"** space on the footer.
Use this selector **".site-footer .container"**. This selector is working only for the "Footer Container". And then add this CSS code -

```
.site-footer .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Front End Screenshot - *https://prnt.sc/txbPYMIeFpDN*

I hope it will help you.
Thank You.